# Is it recommended to trap SIGPIPE in bash script?

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash

I have a problem while executing a bash script from C++ using the system call command.
The script catches a `SIGPIPE` signal and exit with return code `141`.

This problem has started to appear only in the last release of my code.

My Questions are as follows:

1. Why does this SIGPIPE occur now and didn't occur before?
2. Is it safe to ignore the SIGPIPE and what are the consequences?

Comment: Can you post some relevant code snippets?

Comment: As explained in the answers, there is a broken pipe somewhere and hence the `SIPIPE` signal. It means something's wrong in the logic ur using. You should not ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) That's very hard to answer without knowing exactly what you changed.
2) If a sequence of commands appears in a pipeline, and one of the reading commands finishes before the writer has finished, the writer receives a SIGPIPE signal. So whether you can ignore it depends on whether that is acceptable behavior for your script. More info [here](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/bash/E2.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

A [current version of the FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ) that **PiedPiper** linked to states:

> As of bash-3.1, bash does not report SIGPIPE errors by default.  You
>   can build a version of bash that will report such errors.

Is it possible that you changed Bash versions or the way it's built and that caused the change in behavior in your code?